# Having issues transforming columns using to_datetime, what is wrong with the syntax?

Tags: python, date, datetime, types, syntax-error

Really odd, for some reason I get an error attempting to turn two columns into datetime data types

```
pd.to_datetime((data[['Created Date','Close Date']], format = '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

and get:

```
   File "<ipython-input-143-e2e0ef3f1a89>", line 1
pd.to_datetime((data[['Created Date','Close Date']], format = '%m/%d/%Y'))
                                                            ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This should be simple, but not sure what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to remove the space and take it out of the parentheses ex: )format='%m/%d/%Y')

```
pd.to_datetime(data[['a','b']], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```